# Solr search not working properly

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am searching for String Kansas City in description field.
`"q":"description: *Kansas City*"`, but I am getting the results for both Kansas and City. Also it is getting the results from content field as well. I am not sure why it is fetching results from content field. Please suggest me if I am doing any error in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is wrong

```
description:"kansas city"
```

for example

What are the stars for?

Comment: The String kansas city is in the middle of description

Comment: Ugh, the use of * will hit your performance. Just putting your query in quotes should do the trick, solr uses word positions to work out if the phrase matches.

Answer (score 0):

After tokenizing and parsing query it looks like `kansas city` is tokenized into "kansas" and "city" and filters are applied as per fieldtype definition. 
then they are searched in fieldname specified.

`description:*Kansas`

after tokenizing/word splitting, "city" becomes
different word for which you didn't specify fieldname. so by default it is  searched in defaultfield(which is may be `content` in your case)

`defaultsearchfield:city*`

in your case after parsing `description:kansas`and`content:city` you can see the same debugQuery=on with URL in your browser.